# Node.js - Serve file to be downloaded directly from browser without html

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to know if its possible to download a file directly from the browser on a GET request.

#### Let me explain:

I have a node.js API that I'm using to serve some files, and what I want is to directly download them when I make a get request to the resource from my browser. If its possible, what do I have to send? The full binary, pipe the response...? It's a bit confusing to me.

#### The code looks like this:

> server.js

```
app.get('/document', async (req, res) => {
    const { filename } = req.query;

    const filepath = `${os.tmpdir()}/${filename}`
    try {
        var file = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
        return res.status(200).send({ msg: 'File read successfully', file: file })
    } catch (err) {
        return res.send({ msg: 'Problem reading file.', err: err.toString() })
    }

})
```

Comment: Yes its possible, just send the file instead of a html site.

Comment: Right, it worked! But is it possible to set the filename? The filename is coming 'document'

Comment: Assuming the filename you want to use is stored in a `filename` variable, the following should be enough: ``res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${filename}`);``

Comment: It worked as well @IlioCatallo. I solved the problem using another method, from express. `res.download(filepath, filename)` did the trick

Comment: `res.download` is indeed handy if you already have a file on disk. `res.setHeader` might be helpful when, e.g., you have data coming from a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found two ways to solve the problem;

> 1.Using res.download method from express

```
try {
    return res.download(filepath [, filename])
} catch (err) {
    return res.send({ err: 'Problem reading file.', msg: err.toString() })
}
```

> 2. Sending the binaries and a special header

```
try {
        var file = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${filename}`);
        return res.status(200).send(file)
    } catch (err) {
        return res.send({ err: 'Problem reading file.', msg: err.toString() })
    }
```